# Systemd service stops after start (only while booting)

Tags: linux, systemd, service, daemon

I have a minimal systemd service that seems to work normally when started manually using
`systemctl start my-application.service`
And it stops normally using the corresponding stop command.
For some reason during the system boot, the service is correctly started but immediately stopped.
I don't understand why there is a different behaviour in these two cases.

The service is configured like this:

```
[Unit]
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=start-application.sh
ExecStop=stop-application.sh
SendSIGKILL=no
KillMode=none

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

The start-application.sh is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
. /home/me/app-settings

cd /home/me/$APPLICATION/

./$APPLICATION
```

The $APPLICATION variable is read from /home/me/app-settings. It simply starts a simple application (I even tried with an application that does nothing but waits for a CTRL+c).

I want to underline that, it seems to work fine when I start the service manually but, when on boot, it starts and immediately stops (calling the ExecStop command).

Using systemctl status I have different outputs when started automatically on boot and when launched using systemctrl start.

After boot

```
○ gp-application.service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gp-application.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2024-02-19 12:03:09 +01; 19s ago
   Duration: 1.859s
    Process: 586 ExecStart=start-application.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 746 ExecStop=stop-application.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 586 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 64ms

Feb 19 12:03:08 controller su[757]: (to gp) root on none
Feb 19 12:03:08 controller su[757]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user gp(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Feb 19 12:03:08 controller su[757]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session closed for user gp
Feb 19 12:03:08 controller su[760]: (to gp) root on none
Feb 19 12:03:08 controller su[760]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user gp(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Feb 19 12:03:08 controller su[760]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session closed for user gp
Feb 19 12:03:08 controller su[763]: (to gp) root on none
Feb 19 12:03:08 controller su[763]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user gp(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Feb 19 12:03:09 controller su[763]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session closed for user gp
Feb 19 12:03:09 controller systemd[1]: gp-application.service: Deactivated successfully.
```

If started using systemctl start gp-application.service

```
● gp-application.service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gp-application.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2024-02-19 12:04:32 +01; 4s ago
   Main PID: 826 (start-applicati)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 9279)
     Memory: 3.2M
        CPU: 26ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/gp-application.service
             ├─826 /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/start-application.sh
             └─840 . speedy

Feb 19 12:04:33 controller su[837]: (to gp) root on none
Feb 19 12:04:33 controller su[837]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user gp(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Feb 19 12:04:33 controller su[837]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session closed for user gp
Feb 19 12:04:33 controller start-application.sh[840]: SPEEDY 7.0.0
Feb 19 12:04:33 controller start-application.sh[840]: RT-APP-COMMON 2.0.0
Feb 19 12:04:33 controller start-application.sh[840]: 12:04:33.587 utils.cpp                     :117  - utilsInit()                   Utils successfully initialized.
Feb 19 12:04:33 controller start-application.sh[840]: 12:04:33.587 utils.cpp                     :244  - checkAndCreateRTLockFile()    RT lock file: /tmp/.rt-app-lock successfully created.
Feb 19 12:04:33 controller start-application.sh[840]: 12:04:33.587 main.cpp                      :768  - InitProgram()                 Reading font table
Feb 19 12:04:33 controller start-application.sh[840]: 12:04:33.587 fnttable.cpp                  :144  - ReadFontTable()               Error font file font12x8.aff
Feb 19 12:04:33 controller start-application.sh[840]: 12:04:33.587 common-parread.cpp            :83   - readCommonParameters()        EventSocket disabled as requested via parameter file.
```

Comment: Does your application fork? Why do you have `logger` after `./$APPLICATION`?

Comment: You're right, it doesn't make any sense as the application doesn't fork

Comment: An application waiting for Ctrl-C would require a terminal attached, but systemd doesn't provide one because applications started as services are supposed to run in non-interactive mode.

Comment: Yes, that's why in the stop-application.sh I send a kill -INT to stop the application. But the problem it's not that it doesn't stop but that the ExecStop command is called immediately after the ExecStart but ONLY when the system is booting

Comment: Most likely your application stops because you are launching an interactive application in a non-interactive environment. Check your service logs with `systemctl status my-application.service` for more details.

Comment: According to the logs, your application stopped normally with the return code `0`. You need to look into your application - enable additional logging in the application itself, run it with `strace`.

Comment: Can I ask where the various `su` invocations come from? Have you tried replacing the intermediate start-app.sh script with parameters systemd already provides (like WorkingDirectory) to avoid the indirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [AlexD](https://serverfault.com/users/23022/alexd) pointed out, the application was starting but immediately stopped, with exit code 0/SUCCESS.

As specified in the [docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.service.html#ExecStop=), after the application exits with SUCCESS, the ExecStop command is automatically called.

The reason the application stopped is not related to systemd itself, as I could see looking at the application logs, as [AlexD](https://serverfault.com/users/23022/alexd) suggested.